# Moving nav tab based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

I need to move my nav tab to the subscribtion tab if a condition is met.I am blank without any idea. Any of your help is much appreciated.
My HTML code:

```
<div class="matches-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" id="all-matches-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#all-matches" role="tab" aria-controls="all-matches" aria-selected="true">Home</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" id="upcoming-matches-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#upcoming-matches" role="tab" aria-controls="upcoming-matches" aria-selected="false">Upcoming Matches</a></li>

        
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" id="Subscription-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Subscription" role="tab" aria-controls="Subscription" aria-selected="false">Subscription</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="all-matches" role="tabpanel" >
           Tab 1
        </div>
   
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="upcoming-matches" role="tabpanel">
          Tab 2
        </div>
       
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Subscription" role="tabpanel">
        Tab 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the condition

```
if ($scope.balance >= matchfee){
//change the tab to subscription tab
}
```

is met change my tab to subscription.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand from your html code. You need to bind your html data from angularJS controller. EG. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs 'Dynamic Tabs'. For now you can only make it with CSS selectors only

But if you do not want to dynamically manage your tabs you can use ng-class like

```
<li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" id="all-matches-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#all-matches" role="tab" aria-controls="all-matches" aria-selected="true">Home</a></li>

To => ng-class="isActiveTab ? 'active' : '' "
```

Comment: My requirement is to move to subscription tab ,if the condition($scope.balance >= matchfee) is met.how does ng-class="isActiveTab ? 'active' : '' " helps??